# Explicit template instantiation for member function with boolean template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am unsure how to explicitly instantiate a template when the template argument is a bool not a type.  I've boiled my code down to a this short example.  The error I'm getting from clang (using `-std=c++2a`) is:

```
Vec.cpp:13:20: error: explicit instantiation of 'angle' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data
      member
template bool Vec::angle<false>;
```

Here is my code:

Vec.hpp:

```
class Vec {
public:
    template <bool degrees>
    double angle(void);
};
```

Vec.cpp:

```
#include "Vec.hpp"
template <bool degrees>
double Vec::angle(void) {
    if constexpr (degrees) {
        // degree math
        return 360;
    } else {
        // radian math
        return 2*3.14;
    }
}

template bool Vec::angle<false>; // I don't understand what I should put here
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Vec.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    Vec v;
    std::cout << v.angle<false>() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it'd be much more clear if you use an enum to differentiate between `radians` and `degrees`. You really don't want a user to ask whether `angle<false>` is in degrees or radians.

Comment: `template bool Vec::angle<false>;` has a typo. The return value of the function is type `double`, so the explicit instantiation should match: `template double Vec::angle<false>;`

Comment: @MikelRychliski thanks! I tried that but I get the same exact error

Comment: @NicolBolas While I appreciate the comment, I'm planning to use bool like this in many different circumstances (mostly for flags) so my original question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template double Vec::angle<false>();
template double Vec::angle<true>();
```

typo plus you missed the `()` as well.